# Multiple data separated by comma into different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem and I can't seem to get my head around it.

Basically I have a table where in column B different tools are listed:

[image: RAW]

All of them are separated by a comma. Now I want to get rid of column b and fill the data into the corresponding columns.

So that at the end it look like this

[image: Desired End Result]

I tried with a regular `VLOOKUP` but that did not work at all. Then I tried with an `IF` formula, but I can't get my head around how I make the criteria.

```
=IF([@Equipment]=Table2[[#Headers];[Tool1]];"Yes";"No")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(C$19,$B20)),"YES","NO")`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very MUCH! It took me over 3 hours to come to the conclusion that i cant find the answer on my own!!